# swift indexOf for [AnyObject] array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, equatable

Trying to get the index of an array (`[AnyObject]`). What's the part that I'm missing?

```
extension PageViewController : UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
      func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [AnyObject]) {
        let controller: AnyObject? = pendingViewControllers.first as AnyObject?
        self.nextIndex = self.viewControllers.indexOf(controller) as Int?
      }
    }
```

I have tried with Swift 1.2 this approach:

```
func indexOf<U: Equatable>(object: U) -> Int? {
    for (idx, objectToCompare) in enumerate(self) {
      if let to = objectToCompare as? U {
        if object == to {
          return idx
        }
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
```

[image: Type 'AnyObject?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable']
[image: Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'Int?']

Comment: Maybe try it the other way, by casting `self.viewControllers` as `[UIViewController]`?

Comment: @Aderstedt: I'm getting: `Cannot invoke 'indexOf' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject?)'`. Any idea?

Comment: As so often, the *question mark* in the error message is significant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to cast the object we're testing to a `UIViewController`, since we know that are array of `controllers` is holding `UIViewController`s (and we know that `UIViewController`s conform to `Equatable`.

```
extension PageViewController : UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [AnyObject]) {
        if let controller = pendingViewControllers.first as? UIViewController {
            self.nextIndex = self.viewControllers.indexOf(controller)
        }
    }
}
```

The logic behind the error is that in order for the `indexOf` method to compare the object you pass in, it must compare them using the `==` operator.  The `Equatable` protocol specifies that the class has implemented this function, so this is what `indexOf` requires its arguments conform to.

Objective-C doesn't have this same requirement, but the actual Objective-C implementation ends up meaning that the argument is compared with objects in the array using the `isEqual:` method (which `NSObject` and therefore all Objective-C classes implement).

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the viewController property to an Array object:

```
if let controllers = self.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
    self.nextIndex = controllers.indexOf(controller)
}
```

Comment: @nhgrif why would that be expensive?

Comment: Sorry... this particular part might be necessary if `self.viewControllers` isn't already declared as a `[UIViewController]` (it's not clear from the question).  But you missed the part where we need to cast `controller` to a `UIViewController`, as my answer describes.

Comment: Actually, upon a second read of the question, casting the array itself is entirely unnecessary.  Look at the implementation of `indexOf` that's being used.